# Create a link to a local file, but open the browsed folder not the actual file

Tags: model-view-controller, file

I am trying to export a List of items from a web page to the local machine. Upon successfully exporting the list (which it is successful, since the file is there and file.PathExists returns true), I want a link to pop up to the file. Now I want this link to actually open a system browsing window to the location of the file, I do not want them to actually click the link and have it open the file.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

well I solved the issue that I was having, I now save the file to a local server and output a link from here for them to download. I ran into an issue that they could not download it every time the file was recreated. So I just delete the file if it already exists and then make the new file and everything works fine. They can retrieve the file from the server.

Thanks